# How to mentioned PartitionKey -- ConsumerGroup binding in EventHub, Azure

Tags: azure-eventhub

I want to integrate my application through Event Hub with multiple type of devices like Mobile app, different type of Embedded system etc. All different type of senders sending data in their specific format and they need their specific handler as well. Like shown below

```
Mobile APP (Partition key “MobileAPP”) = Consumer Group 1
Embedded System 1 (Partition key “Embedded1”) =  Consumer Group 2
Embedded System 2 (Partition key “Embedded2”) =  Consumer Group 2
```

So can you please tell me how I should specify above binding in Event Hub implementation so that each type of message should handle by their particular consumer group?

Normally I see on Receiver side only default consumer group name mentioned. But I can during `EventProcessorHost`     implementation we can create new Consumergroup with method `namespaceManager.CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists(ehd.Path, consumerGroupName)`. But not able to understand how I make sure that all messages that associate to particular partition key will be handling by their associate consumer group. Where should I mentioned their PartitionKey, ConsumerGroup binding.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no straight forward way to specify PartitionKey to ConsumerGroup binding.

### Here's why:

EventHubs is a high throughput durable stream which offers **stream-level** semantics. 
Simply put, imagine it to be equivalent to a simple in-Memory stream where you get a Cursor on the Stream (using EventHubClient ReceiveByOffset or ReceiveByTimeStamp Api's) and call ReadNext() to get next events. If you want that such a stream to hold events at huge scale - 1 day's worth of data - and you want it to be persistent (cases where even if your app, processing the Stream, crashes, you don't want to loose data) - that's when you need EventHub.

Now coming to your Question, the feature you are for - is to Filter events based on a Property on the Event - which is not a Stream level Operation - but an Event level operation.

Typical approach to implement it yourself - is to Pull events from EventHubs (the event stream) and have a worker to Process (in your case, Filter by PartitionKey) events and push them to individual Queues (or you could even partition your data to push a group of devices to Topics and have subscriptions which pulls data off - with filters).

Now, first question to answer before you decide on using EventHubs is : Do you foresee the Scale requirements offered by EventHubs vs "Directly using ServiceBus Topics" which provides the exact Semantics you are looking for.

HTH!
Sree